# Cannot insert a null into column MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I get this error:

> Cannot insert a null into column (parish.area_code)".

Why do I get that error when I am trying to delete the relationship and how can I fix it? I've tried everything I know but no success. I followed this tutorial [Updating Related Data with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application (6 of 10)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
Code Below:

### parish.cs

```
public partial class parish
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public parish()
    {
        this.application = new HashSet<application>();
        this.application_history = new HashSet<application_history>();
        this.other_owner = new HashSet<other_owner>();
        this.other_owner_history = new HashSet<other_owner_history>();
    }

    public string parish_code { get; set; }
    public string parish_desc { get; set; }
    public string area_code { get; set; }
    public string status_code { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime update_dtime { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<application> application { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<application_history> application_history { get; set; }
    public virtual area area { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<other_owner> other_owner { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<other_owner_history> other_owner_history { get; set; }
}
```

### area.cs

```
public partial class area
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public area()
    {
        this.application = new HashSet<application>();
        this.application_history = new HashSet<application_history>();
        this.parish = new HashSet<parish>();
    }

    public string area_code { get; set; }
    public string area_desc { get; set; }
    public string status_code { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime update_dtime { get; set; }
    public int version_nbr { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<application> application { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<application_history> application_history { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<parish> parish { get; set; }
}
```

### Update Method

```
public void UpdateAreaParishes(string[] selectedParishes, area areaToUpdate)
    {
        if (selectedParishes == null)
        {
            areaToUpdate.parish = null;
            return;
        }
        var selectedParishesHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedParishes);
        var areaParishes = new HashSet<string>(areaToUpdate.parish.Select(x=> x.parish_code));

        foreach (var parish in db.parish)
        {
            if (selectedParishesHS.Contains(parish.parish_code))
            {
                if (!areaParishes.Contains(parish.parish_code))
                    areaToUpdate.parish.Add(parish);
            }
            else
            {
                if (areaParishes.Contains(parish.parish_code))
                {
                    areaToUpdate.parish.Remove(parish);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're just deleting records? To me it looks like `areaToUpdate.parish.Add(parish);` is being executed and that `parish.area_code` is `null`, so when the entity framework context is saved, you get that exception.

Comment: Yes I am update the area record. In updating that record I may add or remove links to parish records and in doing that when removing the parish records it throws that "parish.area_code is null" error

Comment: Run `SELECT FROM parish WHERE area_code IS NULL` on the database. Does it return any results? Edit: I assume the column is non nullable actually, so this is probably a dumb idea. A better question: is the DB column non-nullable? If so, where does that information appear in your model?

Comment: No its not nullable and its a property in the parish class. All my models were generated using Entity Framework the files above are what was generated.